# Flutter getting value from provider show null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a simple controller like this

```
class UserController with ChangeNotifier {
  UserData user = UserData();

  UserData get userdata => user;

  void setUser(UserData user) {
    user = user;
    print(user.sId);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  login(data) async {
    var response = await ApiService().login(data);
    final databody = json.decode(response);
    if (databody['success']) {
      UserData authUser = UserData.fromJson(databody['data']);
      setUser(authUser);
      notifyListeners();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to just print it like this on both widget and in initstate function but values are showing null. I can see in set function value is not null.

```dart
print('id ${context.watch<UserController>().user.sId.toString()}');
print(
    'id2 ${Provider.of<UserController>(context, listen: false).user.sId.toString()}');
```

I already have added

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserController()),
      ],
```

in main.dart in MultiProvider

Also on Tap of login button I am doing this

```
     showLoader(context);
                  UserController auth = Provider.of<UserController>(
                      context,
                      listen: false);

                  var data = {
                    "userEmail":
                        emailController.text.trim().toLowerCase(),
                    "userPassword": passwordController.text.trim(),
                  };
                  auth.login(data).then((v) {
                    if (v) {
                      hideLoader(context);
                      context.go('/homeroot');
                    } else {
                      hideLoader(context);
                      Fluttertoast.showToast(
                          backgroundColor: green,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          msg:
                              'Please enter correct email and password');
                    }
                  });
```

Comment: Where & how are you setting data`sId`?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it's in model I have updated controller also you can see. Also when I am setting user through setUser() I have printed a value and I can see my id there

Answer (score 0):

Try to include `this` while naming is same,

```dart
void setUser(UserData user) {
  this.user = user;
  print(user.sId);
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Follow this structure

```dart
class UserController with ChangeNotifier {
  UserData user = UserData();

  UserData get userdata => user;

  void setUser(UserData user) {
    this.user = user;
    print(user.sId);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> login(String data) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    UserData authUser = UserData(sId: data);
    setUser(authUser);
    notifyListeners();
    return true;
  }
}

class HPTest extends StatelessWidget {
  const HPTest({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Consumer<UserController>(
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return Text(value.user.sId);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {
        final result = await Provider.of<UserController>(context, listen: false)
            .login("new ID");

        print("login $result");
        ;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried not working with this.user

Comment: are you setting value inside print ? or also using tap event for `login`?

Comment: I have updated my question with tap event for login also.

Comment: what do you get from `login` `v`?

Comment: Just returning true false which I get from v so if its false then login failed.

Comment: It is possible to `databody['success']` ==false, try checking data by print/debug. I am adding sample example.

Comment: Try this also but same its not print context.watch<UserController>().user.sId.toString() when I try to print in other page

Comment: `context.watch` inside build method? Maybe you can include sample widget  will help to reproduce the same error

Comment: yeah tried both context.watch and Provider.of in build and class init but both are not working :(